# Как узнать конкретную OS?

Tags: golang

Как узнать конкретную ОС пример: `Windows XP, windows 7` и т.д. `runtime.GOOS` узнает только лишь платформу `windows/linux/darwin`, а узнать конкретную ОС не может. Как узнать конкретную ОС?

Comment: Вызвав соответствующую функцию платформы, для виндовс это функция [GetVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724439(v=vs.85).aspx). Хотите чего-то более универсального - создайте несколько файлов и укажите тег для компиляции, как сделано здесь - [goInfo](https://github.com/matishsiao/goInfo).

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте [goinfo](https://github.com/matishsiao/goInfo).

Установить:

```
go get github.com/matishsiao/goInfo
go build
```

Пример:

```
package main

import (
   "github.com/matishsiao/goInfo"
)

func main() {
    gi := goInfo.GetInfo()
    gi.VarDump()
}
```

Вывод:

```
GoOS: linux
Kernel: Linux
Core: 3.16.51-3+debian
Platform: x86_64
OS: GNU/Linux
Hostname: myserver
CPUs: 1
```